# What is the counterpart of \IEEEauthorrefmark for sig-alternate class?

Tags: ieeetran

What is the counterpart of `\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}` (which is used in the `IEEEtran` class)
for `sig-alternate` class?

Some information about `\IEEEauthorrefmark`

The author parts many times are in the following form:

```
john^, willy^, daniel*
^ University of Washington
* University of Michigan
```

It is used to create the symbols ^*

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct support for shared affiliation addresses in the `sig-alternate` class. Basically, ACM suggest you to give all information for each author in a dedicated `\alignauthor` block.

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\title{My Fancy Paper}
\begin{document}

\author{
% 1st. author
\alignauthor
Ben Trovato\\
             \affaddr{Institute for Clarity in Documentation, Wallamaloo, New Zeeland}\\
             \email{trovato@corporation.com}
\and
\alignauthor
Foo Bar\\
             \affaddr{Institute for Clarity in Documentation, Wallamaloo, New Zeeland}\\
             \email{bar@corporation.com}
\and
\alignauthor
Cool Guy\\
             \affaddr{Cool Stuff Intitute, Cold Village, Iceland}\\
             \email{cool.guy@stuffinstitute.com}
}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This paper...
\end{abstract}

% A category with the (minimum) three required fields
\category{H.4}{Information Systems Applications}{Miscellaneous}
%A category including the fourth, optional field follows...
\category{D.2.8}{Software Engineering}{Metrics}[complexity measures, performance measures]

\terms{Theory}

\keywords{ACM proceedings, \LaTeX, text tagging}

\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't like this or consider it as too space-consuming, you can of course hack around this manually to get the intended result. This is probably not "correct", but I have to admit that I do this for space reasons quite frequently – and nobody ever has complained about it.

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\title{My Fancy Paper}
\begin{document}

\author{
% all authors in one row :-)
\alignauthor
Ben Trovato\textsuperscript{\#}\quad Foo Bar\textsuperscript{\#}\quad Cool Guy\textsuperscript{*}\\
             \affaddr{\textsuperscript{\#}Institute for Clarity in Documentation, Wallamaloo, New Zeeland}\\
             \affaddr{\textsuperscript{*}Cool Stuff Intitute, Cold Village, Iceland}\\
             \email{\{trovato, bar\}@corporation.com}\\
             \email{cool.guy@stuffinstitute.com}
}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This paper...
\end{abstract}

% A category with the (minimum) three required fields
\category{H.4}{Information Systems Applications}{Miscellaneous}
%A category including the fourth, optional field follows...
\category{D.2.8}{Software Engineering}{Metrics}[complexity measures, performance measures]

\terms{Theory}

\keywords{ACM proceedings, \LaTeX, text tagging}

\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]